# SSRS2019 and UNO

Tags: uno-platform

From UNO WinUI App, while calling the WCF async method `Render2Async()` to Render the SSRS Report  through Web Service `http://server/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx`, along with the bunch of other call stack errors it throws the below error. The same works fine in .Net Framework 4.8

**System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.
at SSRS2019.ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient.Render2Async(Render2Request request) in C:\Users\Nmatta\source\repos\MyAppWinUI\MyAppWinUI.Wasm\Connected Services\SSRS2019\Reference.cs:line 4344**

**System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
D:\a\Uno.DotnetRuntime.WebAssembly\Uno.DotnetRuntime.WebAssembly\runtime\src\mono\System.Private.CoreLib\src\System\Threading\Thread.Browser.Mono.cs:line 14**

Answer (score 1):

The library you are using is using threads, which are not supported yet on Wasm platform.

That's why you are getting this `Operation is not supported on this platform` error.

Maybe you should try calling directly the REST API instead of using the dotnet library.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, this validates that the logic moved in .NET API Core returning the byte[] array of the report would be the way to go. And this seems to be working fine now.

Does UNO recommends a way to print the byte[] array to the default printer or a PDF library?